# "CURL: connection refused" when trying to curl localhost: 5000 to container flask

Tags: docker, flask, curl, dockerfile, port

I have a problem executing the command `curl localhost:5000`, can someone give me some help?

```
jesayafernando9@pod-jesayafernando9-node01:~/latihan04$ sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name flask04 jesaya/flask-latihan04
14acc48334060ba79c9f3dd5eaafcc0ea0767d29c531eac0d48ae6649af54e2c
jesayafernando9@pod-jesayafernando9-node01:~/latihan04$ curl localhost:5000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused
jesayafernando9@pod-jesayafernando9-node01:~/latihan04$
```

app.py script

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
        return 'Hey, we have Flask in a Docker container!'


    if __name__ == '__main__':
            app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==0.10.1
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN mkdir /app
RUN apt-get update -y && \
        apt-get install python-pip python-dev -y

COPY ./requirements.txt /app
COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Comment: Does the container start up correctly if you remove the `-d` option?  (The indentation in the Python code you included doesn't look right, and that could be consistent with the symptom you show.)

Comment: Agreed.  This worked as expected for me (with corrected indentation in `app.py`).  You should see something like `Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)` when you run your image without `-d`.  Check the [guide](https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-flask-application) this seems to be from for the corrected file.